# ¿Cuál es mi error en este código? (Java principiante)

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un método llamado calculo2 donde achico la complejidad del método calculo1. Pero lo hice de muchas formas distintas y siempre me da otros resultados.

---

```
public static double calculo1(int n) {
    double prod = 1.0;
    double suma = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            prod = 1.0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                prod = prod * j;
            }
            
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                suma += 1 / prod;
            } else {
                    suma -= 1 / prod;
            }
        }
        return suma;
    }
```

---

```
public static double calculo2(int n) {
    double prod = 1.0;
    double suma = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        prod = 1.0;
        prod = prod * (i+1);
    
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
            suma += 1 / prod;
        else 
            suma -= 1 / prod;
        }
    return suma;
}
```

---

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("c1________________");
        System.out.println(calculo1(9));
        System.out.println(calculo1(2));
        System.out.println(calculo1(3));
        System.out.println(calculo1(12));
        System.out.println("c2----------------");
        System.out.println(calculo2(9));
        System.out.println(calculo2(2));
        System.out.println(calculo2(3));
        System.out.println(calculo2(12));

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no estas disminullendo la complejidad... estas eliminando codigo y no es lo mismo ... la idea es buscar con que remplazar esos dos ciclos for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presta atención a lo que hacen las siguientes líneas:

```
prod = 1.0;
for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    prod = prod * j;
}
```

Hacen la multiplicación de todos los números enteros de 1 a i. (`1 * 2 * 3 * ... * i`)

Mientras que tu lo reemplazas por:

```
prod = 1.0;
prod = prod * (i+1);
```

Más simplemente:

```
prod = i + 1;
```

Porque `prod` vale 1 al ejecutarse la segunda línea. Entonces 1 por cualquier número es ese mismo número.

Claramente no son expresiones equivalentes. Te faltan factores.

---

Toma en cuenta la función original. Cuando llega a esta parte del código:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) 
    suma += 1 / prod;
else 
    suma -= 1 / prod;
```

Cuando `i` es 0, `prod = 1`, cuando `i` es 1, `prod = 1`, cuando `i` es 2, `prod = 1*2`, cuando `i` es 3, `prod = 1*2*3` y así.

Cómo puedes ver, en cada iteración, `prod` vale lo mismo que en la iteración anterior pero multiplicado por un número más.

---

En tu función simplificada vas por bien camino. Solo que debes dejar de restablecer `prod` a 1 cada ciclo y multiplicar solo por `i`.

Sucede que como `i` comienza en 0, la multiplicación te dará 0 pero quieres que en ese momento valga 1. Bueno, simplemente multiplica por `i` solo si `i > 0`.

La función te queda así:

```
public static double calculo2(int n) {
    double prod = 1.0;
    double suma = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        if (i > 0)
            prod *= i;
    
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
            suma += 1 / prod;
        else 
            suma -= 1 / prod;
    }
    return suma;
}
```